# How can I make an environment or couple where I can control which paragraphs are numbered?

Tags: numbering

In LaTeX, how can I write paragraphs where some of them are numbered are some are not?
Like

```
1.1 \textit{repeat} Lorem ipsum.

1.2 \textit{Inner product spaces} Lorem ipsum.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

1.3 \textit{Examples} Lorem ipsum.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

1.4 \textbf{Scharz's inequality} Lorem ipsum.

\textit{Proof}. Lorem ipsum

1.5. \textbf{Theorem} Lorem ipsum

\textit{Proof} Lorem ipsum

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

Ordinary chapter without numbering.

1.6 \textit{Norm space} From previous theorem, one can define \textit{norm spaces} as ...
```

Comment: `\chapter{title}` for numbering and `\chapter*{title}` without numbering: [Numbered and unnumbered sections](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/sections_and_chapters#Numbered_and_unnumbered_sections)

Comment: your question isn't very clear are you referring to paragraphs (as in the title) or chapters (the wording in your example) the actual use case looks more like `\subsection` numbering. or perhaps an environment defined via  `\newtheorem` .